# Why is my router's default gateway changing?

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, modem, gateway

So I have a router connected to my main modem downstairs through a LAN cable, via the LAN ports on both routers. My routers default gateway is usually `192.168.1.1`, and my modem's gateway is `192.168.18.1`. But for some reason whenever I restart my router, my routers gateway is set to my modems gateway... I can't access my routers gateway, I can only access my modem's gateway. But after like a day or so, it changes again and my routers gateway is set back to `192.168.1.1`. Why is this happening?

Also, if its possible, I want to change my routers gateway to my modems gateway, because my router blocks a lot of websites unnecessarily. Basically I want both my modem and router to have the same gateway `192.168.18.1`. How would one go about doing that?

@user1686 I can access this gateway because like I said, after a day it changes back to its default gateway. This is my routers gateway because it says this gateway on the back of the router.
Also I highly doubt it has anything to do with my computer because the random website blocking on the default gateway happens on every device connected, not just my computer.

@harrymc I actually have no idea, I just learnt what a DHCP server is... so I should disable DHCP server on my router right?

Comment: "routers gateway is set to my modems gateway... I can't access my routers gateway" – how do you know what the router's gateway is set to, if you cannot access the router? Do you mean your _computer's_ gateway is set to the modem?

Comment: Which router/modem is the DHCP server (I hope that the answer isn't "both")?

Comment: How are the router and the modem physically connected to each other? Did you use the router's "LAN" port or "WAN" port or something else?

Comment: You should [edit] your question to address the multiple questions we have about your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're saying that your *computer* is showing either the router or the modem *as* the computer's configured gateway, randomly switching between the two.

This usually happens because you have both devices working as DHCP servers on the same network – i.e. it sounds like you've connected the router using its LAN port to the network, and its default configuration is not designed for that.

In short, both your modem *and* your new router are answering the computer's DHCP "lease request" packets, and the computer picks up whichever offer happens to arrive first.

> Also, if its possible, I want to change my routers gateway to my modems gateway, because my router blocks a lot of websites unnecessarily. Basically I want both my modem and router to have the same gateway 192.168.18.1. How would one go about doing that?

The first step is to bypass the router's "router" as such, e.g. by connecting it through the 'LAN' port (instead of the 'WAN' port) to the modem. It sounds like you already have this, because it's what's causing you the problem with gateways (due to incomplete setup), but at the same time it *is* actually what you want if you want to create a single network.

The second step, importantly, is to connect to your router and **turn off its "DHCP server" feature** (and UPnP while you're at it), so that it will not attempt to advertise itself as a gateway – it will only work as a bridge, which is what you're asking for.